# what will I put on href of a link if i have onclick function that determine where the link go

Tags: php

I want to create a link called NEXT that will 1. determine the current page then increment it by 1. I have files like sample-1.php, sample-2.php,sample-3.php etc... So when I'm on sample-1 and click next it will go to sample-2 and so on. 
here is what i got, i i just mix codes from What i think is useful.

```
<a id="asdf" href="$filename" onclick="myfunc"> NEXT </a>

<script>
function myfunc(){
<?php
$filename = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
     list ($name, $ext) = explode['.', $filename);
     list ($basename, $index) = explode['-', $name);
     $index++;
     $filename = $basename.'.'.$index.$ext;
 ?>}
</script>
```

Does it makes sense?

Comment: Nope, it doesn't make any sense...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to use Javascript for this, just PHP:

```
<?php
$filename = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
list ($name, $ext) = explode['.', $filename);
list ($basename, $index) = explode['-', $name);
$index++;
$filename = "$basename-$index.$ext";
echo "<a id='asdf' href='$filename'> NEXT </a>"
```

Comment: This code is correct. @gaxelgaxel, do note the logic behind your code is incorrect.

Comment: You need to append the dash as well: $filename = $basename.'-'.$index.'.'.$ext;

Comment: I've fixed how it calculates the new `$filename`.

Answer (score 1):

This is work for me.

```
<?php
$parts = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$last = end($parts);
$last1 = explode('.', $last);
$last2 = explode('-', $last1[0]);
$cnum = end($last2);

//next number
$filename = $cnum+1;

?>

<a id="asdf" href="$filename" onclick="myfunc"> NEXT </a>
```